# Why is data.table keeping changes to colnames done within a function?

Tags: r, data.table

I have noticed this interesting behaviour of data.tables:

I create a new data.table and use a function to do something to it and change the colnames with `setnames`. In this minimal example only `setnames` is used to change 'B' to 'C':

```
dt1 <- data.table(
   A=c(1:5),
   B=c(6:10))

dt1

> dt1
>    A  B
> 1: 1  6
> 2: 2  7
> 3: 3  8
> 4: 4  9
> 5: 5 10


doSomething <- function(dt){
   setnames(dt, "B", "C")
}

dt2 <- doSomething(dt1)

dt2
> dt2
>    A  C
> 1: 1  6
> 2: 2  7
> 3: 3  8
> 4: 4  9
> 5: 5 10
```

All appears to have worked without an itch. However, looking at dt1:

```
dt1
> dt1
>    A  C
> 1: 1  6
> 2: 2  7
> 3: 3  8
> 4: 4  9
> 5: 5 10
```

After the function dt1 also has a changed colname 'C'. I know that data.tables do not worked in exactly in the same manner as data.frames, in that after certain operations they are not assigned to new objects creating "duplicates". However, in this event a new object get assigned, and still the old object changes after the operation. It somehow reminds of python.

Is this working as intended or should I report it has a bug? Also, is there a way to change this behaviour? I would like to keep dt1 intact after applying a function, with setnames, to it.

Cheers

Comment: If you want to keep original names `dt2 <- copy(dt1); doSomething(dt1)` changes only `dt1`

Comment: This is a FAQ. Be sure to read the package vignettes, in particular the [new ones](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944).

Comment: @akrun please add your comment as an anwser so that I can accept it.

Comment: @Roland, fair enough. It is also mentioned in `?setnames`, but it was not easy to find it (at least for me) in the FAQs. For future reference, it is [here](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html) in section 3b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `copy` of the original dataset ('dt1') and then try `doSomething(dt1)` which will change only 'dt1'

```
dt2 <- copy(dt1)
doSomething(dt1) 

colnames(dt1)
#[1] "A" "C"
colnames(dt2)
#[1] "A" "B"
```